# Random post category URL

Tags: posts, categories, urls

I'm trying to get a random post URL, only in current category.
This is my code, this returns the URL category, :/

```
<?php
 $current_cat = get_the_category(); 
 $randomPost = $wpdb->get_var("
   SELECT guid 
   FROM $wpdb->posts 
   WHERE post_type = 'post' 
   IN wp_terms = $current_cat 
   ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
 echo '<a href="'.$randomPost.'">
   <div id="temporadas-dropdown">EPISODIO AL AZAR</div>
   </a>';
?>
```

Can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro tip - don't custom query unless you need to (you don't). And never use the `guid` field.

```
if ( is_singular() && $cats = get_the_category() )
    $cat_id = $cats[0]->term_id; // Category ID for current post
elseif ( is_category() )
    $cat_id = get_queried_object_id(); // Category ID for current archive
else
    $cat_id = 0; // No cats

$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand', // Here's our random magic
        'cat' => $cat_id,   
    )
);

if ( $posts ) {
    $random_url = get_permalink( $posts[0]->ID );
}
```

Comment: This work but... its return same url. perhaps the cache is bothering ? Thanks for pro tip

Comment: Whoops - change `order` to `orderby`